# Typedef for existing DLL function returns function error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I want to use a DLL in my program which has a function

```
void Set_Callback(Function Pointer)
```

The example code inserts a typedef which obiously doesn't work with my VS C++ 2010

```
typedef void (SET_CALLBACK)(void far pascal (*lpfnPtr)(int));
```

For this line I get an syntax error '*' and 'function returns function' error.

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to understand and read if you break it into two typedefs:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * Function)(int);
typedef void (* SETCALLBACK)(Function pf);
```

in the first typedef, `pascal` becomes `__stdcall` (as `pascal` was for older 16bit systems), and `far` can be dropped as it is superfluous in 32/64-bit architectures

Comment: Shouldn't SETCALLBACK be __stdcall?

Comment: @KitFisto: no, its a using a default convention, thus the `typedef` should too

Comment: I don't have any build error anymore, but now my applications crashes. Is that maybe because of the old DLL and my code not using far pascal anymore?

Comment: Acevou: far pascal is the same as __stdcall, I'd suggest you run it through a debugger and see where it crashes

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
typedef void far pascal (*CallbackType)(Function*);
```